# Mersenne twister random number generator in Java for Monte Carlo Sim.

Tags: monte-carlo, programming, random-walk

I am using the Mersenne twister random number generator in Java for a Monte Carlo Simulation. I need a uniform distribution of values between -1 and 1. My code is below (I am importing [org.apache.commons.math.random.MersenneTwister](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/random/MersenneTwister.html), which is a Apache Commons library that contains the methods I am calling).

```
for(int i = 0; i<= NumberOfTrials-1; i++ ) {  
    MersenneTwister mtsign = new MersenneTwister();  
    boolean sign = mtsign.nextBoolean();            // random true or false  
    MersenneTwister mt = new MersenneTwister();  
    if (sign=true){  
        random[i] = mt.nextDouble(); }  //i.e. (random number between 0 and 1)  
    else if (sign=false){  
        random[i] = - mt.nextDouble(); }   // i.e. random number beween -1 and 0   
}
```

Each index of the resulting array, `random[]`, contains the same value for some reason (and all are positive as boolean keeps returning true). Any thoughts/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I am implementing a Mersenne twister random number generator" -- Actually, you are just _using_ an existing Mersenne twister implementation/library. "Implementing" means writing your own.

Comment: The OP should edit their post to remove the unfounded claim.

Comment: I'm noticing a common Java mistake that you probably have already found and corrected. When you say `if (sign=true)`, you are not just testing sign, you also assigning sign to true and then testing it (and it will always be true). You probably intended to say `if (sign == true)`, but in Java this could (and should) be abbreviated to `if (sign)`. Similar problem with `else if (sign=false)`: you probably intended `else if (sign == false)`. This could be correctly written as simply `else` (because if sign is not true then it must be false).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new random number generator for each iteration. Move `new MersenneTwister()` out of the loop:

```
MersenneTwister mtsign = new MersenneTwister();
MersenneTwister mt = new MersenneTwister();
for(int i = 0; i<= NumberOfTrials-1; i++ ) {
  // use mtsign and mt here
  ...
}
```

Furthermore, you don't need two generators, you can just rescale:

```
MersenneTwister mt = new MersenneTwister();  
for(int i = 0; i<= NumberOfTrials-1; i++ ) {  
   random[i] = mt.nextDouble() * 2 - 1;
}
```

Lastly, in your code, you may need to push the generator even further up the call tree to avoid generating the same sequence repeatedly.

Comment: In practical applications you usually want to recreate the generator (with a fixed seed) for every simulation set, to ensure that the results are reproducible. This is not cryptography, you don't need "true" randomness.

Comment: @quant_dev I smiled when I read: *This is not cryptography*. You're right!